Retrieving secret string from secrets manager with nodejs
When a button is clicked, there should be an alert in the browser with the secret string (secret key and secret value)
This is my react app
const App = () => {

    const handleFileUpload = async () => {
        try{
            await fetch('/get')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {alert(`AccessKeyId: ${data.message} \nSecretAccessKey:             ${data.secretValue}`)
            })
        } catch(e){
            alert(e)
 }};

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleFileUpload}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;


and this is my nodejs which should send the secret string back when the button is clicked
import {SecretsManager, } from "@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager";
import express from "express"
import AWS from "aws-sdk"

const app = express();
const PORT = 5000;

const handler = async () => {
    AWS.config.update({'region':'region'});
    const client  = new SecretsManager({'region':'region'})
    const SecretsManagerResult = await client.getSecretValue({
      SecretId: "secrets_manager_name",
    })

    let responseObj = JSON.parse(SecretsManagerResult.SecretString);
      
    const {clsa_key, clsa_secret} = responseObj;
    return {clsa_key, clsa_secret}
};

app.get('/get', async (req, res) => {
    try { 
        let secretData = await handler()
        res.json({
            message: 'Secret retrieved successfully',
            "secretValue": secretData,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({
            message: 'Error retrieving secret',
            "secretValue": error.message,
        });
}})

handler is copy-pasted from code source from Lambda/Functions/FunctionName, the function does the job when I run over is code source (AWS cloud 9) but I'm not sure why it doesn't run in my code (using VScode).
I've set up the secrets manager and the role with the permission to get the secret value but I keep getting the could not load credentials from any providers soluition.
I've tried using
import { LambdaClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-lambda"

const invokeLambda = async () => {
    const lambda = new LambdaClient({ region: "us-west-1" });
    const functionName = mylambdafunction;  
    const input = { t
        FunctionName: "mylambdafunction", 
      }  
        command = new InvokeAsyncCommand(input);
      try{
        response = await lambda.send(command)
        }catch(e){
        console.log(e.message)
    return response;
};

I was expecting invokeLambda to work but I keep getting the same error and now I'm quite lost.
I've looked over the javascript sdk documentation but couldn't make up what is going wrong in my code.
And here is my lambda function configurations
Allow: secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy
Allow: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
Allow: secretsmanager:DescribeSecret
Allow: secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds

and for Execution role I have roleExample which has a policy with the following actions
GetResourcePolicy
GetSecretValue
ListSecretVersionIds```


you didn't supplied the iam accesskey and secret while initialising client

You don't want to use a .env file to set your AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. SecretsManager is good for storing database passwords and usernames etc but to first make the api calls to SecretsManager or to use any of the sdk locally you need to set up a credentials file as per the docs. If running on an EC2 instance you can use IAM roles instead.


I keep getting the could not load credentials from any providers soluition in console ?

Why that code does not working in local machine ?
Simple, aws lambda has some pre defined environment variable See here that doesn't configured in your local. So that function will execute there perfectly without any configuration like region,accessKeyId.
What you have to do is some configuration of env variables or you can directly pass as argument to the client initiator function.
I will recommend to use .env because you don't want to same multiple times when using another service.
Let me show both examples.
This is the aws client initiator object, i'm only covering the basic properties required to initialise a client.

Configuring .env

AWS_REGION = your region
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = your iam access keyid
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = your iam secret key

Then initialise client like
const client  = new SecretsManager(); // it will take details from process.env


Using manual configuration

const client  = new SecretsManager({
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: yourAccess keyId,
        secretAccessKey: your SecretAccess Key
    },
    region: your region
});


I see, what if I don't want to hardcode the access key id and secret access key? what are the alternatives or the best practice in this case?

you can use env that will be the best case

your code works but I'm confused now because here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-retrieve it says "To increase database security, we recommend that you use AWS Secrets Manager instead of environment variables to store database credentials. For more information, see Using AWS Lambda with Amazon RDS." so how do we retrieve the keys from a secrets manager if we need the keys to access the manager and retrieve its secret keys in the first place?

By default, Lambda uses an AWS managed key for environment, If you want more encryption see on environment encryption section. You don't need any RDS
